# What is wrong with my rich snippets? Where are my stars?

Tags: schema

According to google's Structured Data Testing Tool, there are no errors in my review schema code, but the stars still are not displaying in the preview. Does anyone have any idea why? I thought maybe it was a nesting issue, but I tried to organize the data in all kinds of arrangements and to no avail. Any thoughts would be very appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Here's the page I'm referring to: 
http://www.junkluggers.com/locations/westchester-ny/white-plains-ny-junk-removal-and-furniture-pickup/

(The review I'm working on is the one at the bottom of the page, not the testimonial on the right sidebar.)

Comment: Try checking it without the www on the front.  Believe it or not, they may resolve different ways.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google:

" If you've added structured data for rich snippets, but they are not appearing in search results, the problem can be caused by two types of issues:

- Technical issues with the structured data markup or with the Google’s ability to crawl, index, and utilize the structured data.
- Quality issues, that is, structured data that is technically correct, but does not adhere to Google’s quality guidelines."

**Full answer here:** https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1093493?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Along with RustyFluff's comment, I do notice a few technical errors in your markup, Catherine.  In a nutshell, you haven't defined who or what is being reviewed, and you should be using the reviewBody property instead of description.  You also should remove the city from within the author's name markup.  And something else that I should point out is that you should remove the authorship markup from the page, as it's not appropriate for an authorship tag according to [Google's guidelines](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2013/08/relauthor-frequently-asked-advanced.html?).  Also, the publisher tag only needs to go on your homepage, and it should link to your Google+ business page, not to a personal profile.

Keep in mind, though, that even if your markup is technically perfect, there are no guarantees that Google will display your rich snippets.  They determine that based on, among other things, various quality signals.